# Convolution in Fourier domain

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis, convolution

I am computing the convolution of a disk `Img` in 2D numerical matrix form with a kernel `Ker` in the Fourier domain but the output image of the disk `Convolved` is not centered. The disk image after convolution appears to be shifted to the upper left region of the matrix.

The code:

```
ifftshift[dat_?ArrayQ, k : (_Integer?Positive | All) : All] :=
      Module[{dims = Dimensions[dat]}, 
             RotateRight[dat, If[k === All, Ceiling[dims/2], 
             Ceiling[dims[[k]]/2] UnitVector[Length[dims], k]]]]   

ImFourier[Img_] := 
            Module[{KerFun, Ker, FourierMul, Convolved},  
                   KerFun[{x_, y_}] := ( E^(-500 x^2 - 700 y^2));  (* kernel function  *)
                   Ker = Table[KerFun[{x, y}], {x, -0.5, 0.5, 0.032}, {y, -0.5, 0.5, 0.032}];
                   FourierMul = InverseFourier[Fourier[Img]*Fourier[Ker]];
                   Convolved = Rescale[Chop[ifftshift[FourierMul]]];
                   {Return[Convolved], Return[FourierMul]}];

{Convolved, FourierMul} = ImFourier[DiskMatrix[13, 32]];
ArrayPlot[Convolved, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

How do I get a centered image from the Fourier domain convolution?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is due to the slight assymetry that arises if your image dimensions are even. With an even number $n = 2k$ of degrees of freedom per dimension, there is also an even number of Fourier coefficients computed, namely for the basis functions $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} (k-1)\,t}, \dotsc, \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\,t}, 1, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,t}, \dotsc, \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k\,t}$. That is, the mirror image of $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k\,t}$ cannot be represented.

For example, using odd image dimensions seems to work well:

```
ImFourier[Img_] := Module[{KerFun, Ker, FourierMul, Convolved, m, n},
   {m, n} = Dimensions[Img];
   Ker = Outer[{x, y} \[Function] (E^(-500 x^2 - 700 y^2)), 
     Subdivide[-0.5, 0.5, m - 1], Subdivide[-0.5, 0.5, n - 1]];
   FourierMul = InverseFourier[Fourier[Img]*Fourier[Ker]];
   Convolved = Rescale[Chop[ifftshift[FourierMul]]];
   {Convolved, FourierMul}];

n = 33;
{Convolved, FourierMul} = ImFourier[DiskMatrix[13, n]];
ArrayPlot[Convolved, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

Comment: Any workaround to have even dimensions?.